# Adjust the width of the mat-side-nav while it is open

Tags: css, angular, html, angular-material, mat-sidenav

When the nav-bar is clicked open, the width of the nav-bar is to be adjusted automatically with the content.

```
 <mat-sidenav #sidenav  mode="side" class="primary-color main-sidenav nav- 
 shadow" opened="true" [@sidenavState]="sidenavState" 
 (@sidenavState.done)="endAnimation()" *ngIf="layout === 'modern' || 
 forceModern">
 ....
 </mat-sidenav>
```

When I set the width of the side-nav in SCSS as

```
.mat-side-nav{
   width: auto !important
 }
```

The nav-bar is opened by default without being clicked to open. Also it is not closed with the click

Comment: Is that not the default behaviour? Seems to be when I'm playing around with Stackblitz... https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fm64xa?file=app/sidenav-open-close-example.html

Answer (score 0):

Your problem:
when you are doing the below:
.mat-side-nav{
   width: auto !important
 }

This is kind of hard coding the width to take whatever it contains.

Solution:
Find the class which is active while its open and set the width: auto, for that class.